# Calculations using table cell values, plus sub total and grand total

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have been struggling for a long time on this one.
( I started a thread on this over a year ago.. then gave up due to failing)
Have googled and searched for bits of code on SO but not had much joy in completing it.

I have a table, which is populated from php/sql.

on a tr it will have

```
cost    qty1    qty2    qty3    Lineqty  Linecost
```

I need the total of qty1,qty2,qty3 in lineqty, and the linecost will be prod_cost * lineqty

here is the jQuery I have so far...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".qty").each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
      calculateTotal($(this).parent().index());
    });
  });
});

function calculateTotal(index) {
  var total = 0;
  $('table tr td .row_total').filter(function() {
    if ($(this).index() == index) {
      total += parseFloat($(this).find('.qty').val()) || 0;
    }
  });
  $('table tr td.totalCol:eq(' + index + ')').html(total);
  calculateSum();
  calculateRowSum();
}

function calculateRowSum() {
  $('table tr:has(td .qty)').each(function() {

    var sum = 0;
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      sum += parseInt($(this).find('.qty').val()) || 0;
    });

    var costeach = 1.49;
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      costeach += parseFloat($(this).find('.prod_cost').val());
    });

    var rowsum = sum * costeach;
    $(this).find('td .row_total').html(sum);
    $(this).find('td .row_sum').html(rowsum);

  });
}

function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  $("td.row_total").each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).html()) || 0;
  });
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Here is output table:

```
<table>
  <thead class="header">
    <tr>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>1.2 %</th>
      <th>1.8 %</th>
      <th>Tester</th>
      <th>2.4 %</th>
      <th>Line Qty</th>
      <th>Line Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Flavoured NM-Line Available liquidrow">
      <th class="prod_cost price">1.90</th>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input tabindex="-1" class="form-control" value="1" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td><span class="row_total"></span>
        <span class="row_cost"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Flavoured NM-Line Available liquidrow">
      <th class="prod_cost price">1.9</th>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input tabindex="-1" class="form-control" value="1" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td><span class="row_total"></span>
        <span class="row_cost"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Flavoured NM-Line Available liquidrow">
      <th class="prod_cost price">1.90</th>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input tabindex="-1" class="form-control" value="1" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td><span class="row_total"></span>
        <span class="row_cost"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Minty NM-Line New liquidrow">
      <th class="prod_cost price">1.9</th>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input tabindex="-1" class="form-control" value="1" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input min="1" step="1" class="qty form-control" type="number">
      </td>
      <td><span class="row_total"></span>
        <span class="row_cost"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="totalColumn">
      <td class="totalCol" align=right>Total:</td>
      <td class="totalCol" align=right></td>
      <td class="totalCol" align=right></td>
      <td class="totalCol" align=right></td>
      <td class="totalCol" align=right></td>
      <td class="totalCol" align=right></td>
      <td class="totalCol" align=right></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My current jfiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/o9cpb0fL/6/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the above codes to what im at now.
If I enter a qty on one of the lines, that figure * .prod_cost is calculating.
Im struggling getting the total of all .quantity on that row
I realise this must be in a each loop

Comment: I have now managed to get the total qty per line.. but cant get the value of prod_cost, so that i can calculate the total cost per line

Comment: is anybody able to assist me on this one.